# GCE server not coming back after reboot - error in /usr/share/google/virtionet-irq-affinity

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Have a Debian 7 server ("stash") on Google Compute Engine that we initially created about a year ago.  Have rebooted occasionally, but not often.

Rebooted today and ran into issues.  Overall, the machine status is "running" and the console log shows our application (Stash) was initialized and Tomcat was started.  But, it is not really running; and we are not even able to SSH into the machine.

Noticed the following at the end of the console log:

> [   18.215891] postgres (2173): /proc/2173/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/2173/oom_score_adj instead.
>
> Aug 10 01:19:27 stash kernel: [   18.215891] postgres (2173): /proc/2173/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/2173/oom_score_adj instead.
>
> [....] Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main [?25l [?1c 7 [1G[ [32m ok [39;49m 8 [?25h [?0c.
>
> Cannot get device channel parameters
>
> : Operation not supported
>
> /usr/share/google/virtionet-irq-affinity: line 56: [: : integer expression expected
> Aug 10 01:21:28 stash google: onboot initializing

Any suggestions on what is happening or how we can boot the machine such that we can SSH into?

Comment: Do you still have the issue ?

Comment: No answer to the why the Google script stopped working.  But, the answer from Google was essentially to rebuild a virtual machine using a snapshot of the original disk (fixing whatever caused the problem).  Which is what I had already done.  So bottom line, no clue why it stopped working but also not spending anytime investigating it since I rebuilt new server and reloaded application data from copy of the snapshot.